# Kafka Streams: How to get the first and the last record of a SessionWindow?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

By default, `.windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(Duration.ofSeconds(60))` returns a record for each incoming record.

Combined with a `.count()` and a `.filter()` it's easy to retrieve the first record.

Using
`.suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(unbounded()))` it's also easy to retreive the last record.

So… I do the processing twice, as you can see the adapted word count example:

```java
final KStream<String, String> streamsBranches = builder.<String,String>stream("streams-plaintext-input");

streamsBranches
  .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).split("\\W+")))
  .groupBy((key, value) -> ""+value)
  .windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(Duration.ofSeconds(60)).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(2)))
  .count(Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()))
  .toStream()
  .map((wk, v) -> new KeyValue<>(wk.key(), v == null ? -1l : v))
  .filter((wk, v) -> v == 1)
  .to("streams-wordcount-output", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));

streamsBranches
  .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).split("\\W+")))
  .groupBy((key, value) -> ""+value)
  .windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(Duration.ofSeconds(60)).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(2)))
  .count(Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()))
  .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(unbounded()))
  .toStream()
  .map((wk, v) -> new KeyValue<>(wk.key(), v))
  .filter((wk, v) -> v != null)
  .to("streams-wordcount-output", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));
```

But I wonder whether there is a simpler and more beautiful way of doing the same.

Comment: What kind of the first and last record would you like to get? You using grouping based on different _keys_, so I think It won't work as you expected.

Comment: The different keys are used to illustrate what I want. I edited the post to remove them to make it more clear. I just want to get the first and the last record from a sessionwindow.

Comment: I think your code still doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `SessionWindowedKStream::aggregate(...)` and based on your logic accumulate the result in *aggregator* (first and last value)

Sample code might looks like that:

```java
streamsBranches.groupByKey()
        .windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(Duration.ofSeconds(60)).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(2)))
        .aggregate(
                AggClass::new,
                (key, value, oldAgg) -> oldAgg.update(value),
                (key, agg1, agg2) -> agg1.merge(agg2),
                Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), new AggClassSerdes())
        ).suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(unbounded()))
        .toStream().map((wk, v) -> new KeyValue<>(wk.key(), v))
.to("streams-wordcount-output", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), new AggClassSerdes()));
```

Where `AggClass` is accumulator and `AggClassSerdes` is Serdes for that accumulator

```java
public class AggClass {
    private String first;
    private String last;

    public AggClass() {}

    public AggClass(String first, String last) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
    }

    public AggClass update(String value) {
        if (first == null)
            first = value;
        last = value;
        return this;
    }

    public AggClass merge(AggClass other) {
        if (this.first == null)
            return other;
        else return new AggClass(this.first, other.last);
    }
}
```